# how to show data that get from selected listview in another activity

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-intent

i have an app where in a form show the list view. the user can click one of the list view and when clicking the app will move to another activity and it's activity will show some data based on "code" that sent from the list view form. my app is success to move in another activity but doesn't show the data. please help me.
Thank you.

This is my code in list view form :

```
final ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);

        String url = "http://192.168.43.244/wewash/listview.php";
        try {

             JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));
             final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
             HashMap<String, String> map;
             for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                 JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                 map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                 map.put("nama", c.getString("nama"));
                 map.put("tanggal_keluar", c.getString("tanggal_keluar"));
                 MyArrList.add(map);
             }

             SimpleAdapter sAdap;
             sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(halaman_utama.this, MyArrList, R.layout.listview,
             new String[] {"nama", "tanggal_keluar","id", ""}, new int[] {R.id.tsnama, R.id.tstglk, R.id.kode, R.id.tsspasi}); 
             lv.setAdapter(sAdap);
             lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
             {
                 @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                            long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String kode = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.kode)).getText().toString();
                        Intent in = new Intent(halaman_utama.this, p_daftar_pakaian.class);
                        //menampilkan value dari item yg diklik
                        in.putExtra("id", kode);
                        startActivity(in);
             }
                     });

                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     }
```

and it's my code in new activity :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String kode = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        String url = "http://192.168.43.244/wewash/listview_detail.php?id="+kode;

        try {

             JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));
             for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
                 JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                 String idpk = c.getString("id");
                 String namapk = c.getString("nama");
                 String paketpk = c.getString("paket");
                 String cbiasapk = c.getString("cbiasa");
                 String ckhususpk = c.getString("ckhusus");
                 String tglantarpk = c.getString("tanggal_keluar");
                 String totalpk = c.getString("total");
                // String nomorpk = c.getString("no_hp");
                 atasnama.setText(namapk);
                    ereview.setText("Id Pelanggan : " +idpk+
                            "\nNama Pelanggan : "+namapk+
                            "\nPaket : "+paketpk+
                            "\nCucian Biasa : "+cbiasapk+" kg"+
                            "\nCucian Khusus : "+ckhususpk+" item"+
                            "\nTotal : "+totalpk+" rupiah"+
                            "\nTanggal Antar : "+tglantarpk);
                  //  enomer.setText(nomorpk);      
            }
        } catch (JSONException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and it's the php file

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("wewash");

$kode=$_GET["id"];

$sql=mysql_query("select * from pakaian where id='$kode'"); 
$arrayId=array();

if($sql === FALSE) { 
die(mysql_error());
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
  $arrayId["id"]=$row["id"];
  $arrayId["nama"]=$row["nama"];
  $arrayId["tanggal_keluar"]=$row["tanggal_keluar"];
  $arrayId["paket"]=$row["paket"];
  $arrayId["cbiasa"]=$row["cbiasa"];
  $arrayId["ckhusus"]=$row["ckhusus"];
  $arrayId["total"]=$row["total"];
}

echo json_encode($arrayId);
?>
```

Comment: Use `Log.e("kode", kode);` in your first activity to see what code contains

Comment: @AlbertoFernández i have tried and when i run in my device, no error show in logcat. i dont know, its confusing me. need help please

Comment: Did you put it in your onItemClick method? If you did it, It should show an error in your logcat (sometimes you need to launch the Android Device Monitor, in the toolbar, to see the error). If after doing this you don't see any error that means that onItemClick is not being called, so look for that in Google.

Comment: @AlbertoFernández yep absolutely i put in onItemClick method. first, i put in a catch statement and there's no error in logcat. then i tried to put in try statement and show the error. In the text column of error logcat only said "kode". i don't really know what is the meaning. Logcat also showing the warning message that said: org.json.JSONException: Value {} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray.
is this warning causing my problem ?

Comment: Yes, It seems you have an error parsing the JSON here `JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));` or in the loop, and for that reason kode is empty and catch is called. Post JSON data in order to help you

Comment: @AlbertoFernández solved. thanks anyway :))